# Adding elements back to a list of list

Tags: python-2.7

Hi please i want to loop through temp add a B suffix to the elements of B and store them back into their original positions, how can I do that. I tried this and it only stores all the new elements as individuals in nodes.

```
temp = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

nodes = []
for j in temp:
   for i in j:
    nodes.append('%s' %  i + 'B')
print nodes
```

desired output:

```
temp = [[1B,2B,3B,4B],[5B,6B,7B,8B],[9B,10B,11B,12B]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @sshashank, however the output is exactly what i got previously. I kind of need the new list embedded in a list of list format.

Comment: Just asking, how do you expect your variable `bus_route_nodes` to exist without assigning anything to it?

Comment: @applepi, that was a typo, i have updated it. Thanks. Can you help now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
temp = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

nodes = [map(lambda x: str(x) + 'B', l) for l in temp]                        
print nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
for i,selection in enumerate(temp):
    for j,element in enumerate(selection):
        temp[i][j] = str(element)+ "B"
```